# local client server node secure authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, https, client-server

I am currently developing a software suite built on the MEAN stack and designed to run locally(This app will not being deployed on the web).

The node apps mentioned below will be compiled into executables with pkg(npm package). I have yet to confirm if this package offers any security to my node apps.

The architecture of the project is as follows:

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t77ok.png)

- Node Client running on locahost port 3000
- Node Api running on localhost port 5000
- Local mongodb on the default port of 27017.
- Local desktop application used to record data for transmission to the database.

I need to satisfy these final requirements:

- Users should not have direct access to the database and can only view
  data through their local client.
- The api should only communicate with my client, my application and my database. There needs to be some mechanism for validating clients of the api.

So, I guess **I need a way of having a secure connection between these components without having to save credentials in files within the app.**

I understand how to add authentication to Mongodb but I can't think of a way to avoid having to have these credentials in plaintext within my code. I am in the same situation with regard to .crt and .key files for client server validation. 
Please forgive me if I am missing something obvious, its gotten to a tunnel vision stage for me and I just need some fresh eyes.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use **json web token** for authentication. Reference: https://jwt.io/
You will find nice articles from the topic, if you make a quick google search on it.

Comment: I like the look of JWTs, very nice, however unless I missed something I will still be required to have a file within my project which stores a private key and still the code is local and potentially readable(again I am unaware of whether or not PKG by veit offers any security advantages). 
Is it possible to implement this level of client server authentication with specifying secret keys in code or files.